# MS-Access query - Including Null values in with other conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Please help  as this is aquery with many parameters but when it said 
" **((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate) Like IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![NoDevDate]=-1,"*",""))** " it should have included null values aswell but it is not if I am putting **or Is null** with this criteria then it is being applied for both conditions regardless of check box is checked or not. Please help getting the null values included when checkbox is checked.

**Please have look on screenshots:**

[Query in design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4xxF.png)

[Criteria Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYU2D.png)

**Query:**

```
SELECT OrderCustMain.OdrID, OrderCustMain.CustName, OrderCustMain.CustEmail,
OrderCustMain.OdrDate, OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate, Date()-
[OrderCustMain]![OdrDate] AS [Days Past], OrderCustMain.OrderStatus, 
OrderProdDetails.BrandName, OrderProdDetails.ModelName, 
OrderProdDetails.Priority, SupplierDetails.SupEmail, OrderProdDetails.Status 
FROM SupplierDetails INNER JOIN (OrderCustMain INNER JOIN OrderProdDetails 
ON OrderCustMain.[OdrID] = OrderProdDetails.[OrdID]) ON 
SupplierDetails.SupOrgName = OrderProdDetails.BrandName WHERE 
(((OrderCustMain.OdrDate) Like IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[NoStDate]=-1,"*","")) AND ((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate) Like 
IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![NoDevDate]=-1,"*","")) AND ((Date()-
[OrderCustMain]![OdrDate])>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![cboDaysPast]) 
AND ((OrderCustMain.OrderStatus) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus])) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.BrandName) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]))) OR 
(((OrderCustMain.OdrDate)>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[RepCritOdrStDate] And (OrderCustMain.OdrDate)<=[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrEndDate]) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate)>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[RepCritDlvryStDate] And (OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate)<=[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritDlvryEndDate]) AND ((Date()-
[OrderCustMain]![OdrDate])>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![cboDaysPast]) 
AND ((OrderCustMain.OrderStatus) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus])) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.BrandName) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]))) OR (((OrderCustMain.OdrDate) 
Like IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![NoStDate]=-1,"*","")) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate)>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[RepCritDlvryStDate] And (OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate)<=[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritDlvryEndDate]) AND ((Date()-
[OrderCustMain]![OdrDate])>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![cboDaysPast]) 
AND ((OrderCustMain.OrderStatus) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus])) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.BrandName) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]))) OR 
(((OrderCustMain.OdrDate)>=[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[RepCritOdrStDate] And (OrderCustMain.OdrDate)<=[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrEndDate]) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate) Like IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[NoDevDate]=-1,"*","")) AND ((Date()-[OrderCustMain]![OdrDate])>=[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![cboDaysPast]) AND ((OrderCustMain.OrderStatus) 
Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),"*",
[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus])) AND 
((OrderProdDetails.BrandName) Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]),"*",[Forms]!
[ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritBrandName]))) ORDER BY   
OrderCustMain.OdrID, OrderProdDetails.Priority;
```

Comment: Seriously? you expect us to try to understand this?!

Comment: The _least_ you could've done would've been to put some line breaks and indentation in there.

Comment: I think your query should look like this: `((OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate IS NULL AND checkBoxState = 1) OR OrderProdDetails.DeliveryDate = <some date>`).

Answer (score 1):

The primary source for your trouble is that dates are not strings, so "Date Like some-string" will either fail or return unintended results.

You'll have to redesign this from scratch. Exactly how depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
WHERE Nz(OrderCustMain.OdrDate, #1/1/1900#) >= IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[NoStDate]=-1,Nz(OrderCustMain.OdrDate, #1/1/1900#),[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]!
[RepCritOdrStDate])
```

It might simplify the code.